# How to use the map function to input JSON data into a div element

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an API URL which is this

https://api-amvstrm.nyt92.eu.org/api/v1

/popular and the API response looks like this

```
t

itle": "Dungeon Meshi",

      "id": "dungeon-meshi",

      "image_url": "https://gogocdn.net/cover/dungeon-meshi-1704169699.png",

      "released": "2024"
```

And so I want to use the map function in js to redirect the data from the API into this html container

```
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="product__item__text">

                                        <ul>

                                            <li>Active</li>

                                            <li>Movie</li>

                                        </ul>

                                        <h5><a href="#">Kizumonogatari III: Reiket su-hen</a></h5>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">

                                <div class="product__item">

                                    <div class="product__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/popular/popular-3.jpg">

                                        <div class="ep">18 / 18</div>

                                        <div class="comment"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 11</div>

                                        <div class="view"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 9141</div>
```

Is there a way I can use the js map function to only display the title and image picture only ? Thanks ki

Comment: Does your API return one item or multiple items?

Comment: The data you're showing is not valid JSON.  Presumably it's a small part of the overall JSON, but we can't really assume anything about what we can't see.  As for the question itself... `.map()` is a function which iterates over an array and projects the values of that array into a new array (of the same length).  You can use it to perform any operation which does that.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: I'm new JavaScript so I don't really understand much of it

Comment: So, what led you the `map()` function? Your html is fragmented and hard to tell what it's supposed to be showing.

Comment: `.map()` is used to convert ("map") values from one format to another - you pass in your source and provide a mapping function, retrieving an array as the result.  If you don't want/need that converted result, then you can use any iterating method, such as `for` `for in` `for of` `forEach` or jquery's `$.each`.  eg you could use map to convert your data to HTML and then add to the DOM, or you could use `forEach` to add each item to the DOM as you go.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say this is your API EndPoint :
https://api-amvstrm.nyt92.eu.org/api/v1

Now, Firstly you have to fetch this API in your javascript code. Wait i am showing you how you can fetch.

```js
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api-amvstrm.nyt92.eu.org/api/v1');
      // Replace with your API endpoint
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }
```

Then you can create a function to display the fetched data like this:

```
 // Function to display data on the screen
async function displayData() {
  const dataContainer = document.getElementById('data-container');
  
  // Fetch data from the API
  const posts = await fetchData();

  // Check if data exists
  if (posts && posts.length > 0) {
    const postsHTML = posts.map(post => `
      <div key=${post.id}>
        <h2>${post.title}</h2>
        <p>${post.released}</p>
      </div>
    `).join('');

    // Display data on the screen
    dataContainer.innerHTML = postsHTML;
  } else {
    dataContainer.innerHTML = '<p>No posts found</p>';
  }
}
```

and then you can call this displayData function to fetch the details.